# Calling method from Activity in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, non-static

I have one Activity (1) that has two fragments. This Activity extends to another one (2) with base methods that I commonly use in my application. So I want to call a method from (2) after I click on one button that is located in one of the fragments from (1), what is the best way to do this?

I am trying to do it like this:

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(isValid()){
                    AndroidUtils.hideKeyboard(email, getActivity());
                    AuthenticationActivity.login(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

But it says that a non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context. So I tried to do this:

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(isValid()){
                    AndroidUtils.hideKeyboard(email, getActivity());
                    AuthenticationActivity instance = new AuthenticationActivity();
                    instance.login(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
((AuthenticationActivity)getActivity()).login(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
```

and make your login function non-static

Comment: While this solution might work, you can do it way better:  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you mind explaining to me what is the difference between your alternative and the code I used?

Comment: In java you can use typecasting. if your problem is solved, please accept and vote up

Comment: @MarcosGuimaraes Basically you set up an interface to communicate with your activity, which is a cleaner approach than casting your activity and having a public method in it, which probably should not be public. When you want to communicate a lot more with your activity from a fragment, you should totally take a look at it.